# How can I click on a button and trigger a javascript function in webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, button

How can I click on button-x in the following code? No id is available

```
class="image" onclick="javascript:set()" type ="button" value="x"
```

Have tried with link text and //a for xpath etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css selector like:

```
[onclick*='set']
```

Answer (score 0):

open selenium IDE then click on "find" button drag mouse to the specific element where you want to locate then click on the element. now you are able to find different locator values in the target field.

You can choose any one of them to execute program successfully.

Still the problem exists then share HTML code and your selenium code.

Comment: <input class="image" onclick="javascript:setImp()" type="button" value="Import">

Comment: did u try with selenium IDE? //input[@class='image'][@value='import'] i think this xpath is enough. if still problem exists then check weather it is present in frame/div tag/span tag. then u may be get some clue to find the answer

Comment: I have already tried with the one generated by IDE , its not recognising it. And it is not in div nor in span tags

Comment: Hi Ravi,It is present in IFrame

Comment: ok fine @sangeetha, then enter into frame by using driver.switchTo().frame(0); if you have two or more frames then specify last frame number in frame(). Then after writing the code close the frame using driver.switchTo().defaultContent();